# How do you implement the "IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()" method in IDictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, enumeration

I'm creating a dictionary data structure which implements the IDictionary interface. I'm stuck when it comes to implementing the [GetEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9eb7a3t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. I have an enumerator which gives KeyValuePair instances but from what I'm finding, I have to implement IDictionaryEnumerator.

Is there a simple way to transform a KeyValuePair enumerator to an IDictionaryEnumerator? I know I can do the following hack:

```
IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return new Dictionary(this.KeyValueEnumerator()).GetEnumerator();
}
```

But it seems very inefficient as it loads all the enumerator data.

Comment: What in the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionaryenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) of implementing `IDictionaryEnumerator` prevented you from creating your own version of `SimpleDictionaryEnumerator`?

Comment: You should really implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` rather than the non-generic version.

Comment: @Servy Dammit I didn't realize I was looking up the non-generic version on MSDN!

Comment: When in doubt, [check the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,663) of an actual implementation

Answer (score 0):

Given that you told us that you have a `KeyValueEnumerator()` that returns a `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<,>>`

```
// This you told us you have
public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> KeyValueEnumerator()
{
    return something;
}
```

I built a `MyDictionaryEnumerator` that exposes a `IDictionaryEnumerator` interface

```
// This is what you need
public IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return new MyDictionaryEnumerator(KeyValueEnumerator());
}

public class MyDictionaryEnumerator : IDictionaryEnumerator
{
    public MyDictionaryEnumerator(IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> enumerator)
    {
        Enumerator = enumerator;
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> Enumerator;

    public DictionaryEntry Entry
    {
        get { return new DictionaryEntry(Enumerator.Current.Key, Enumerator.Current.Value); }
    }

    public object Key
    {
        get { return Enumerator.Current.Key; }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return Enumerator.Current.Value; }
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get { return Entry; }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return Enumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Enumerator.Reset();
    }
}
```

The `MyDictionaryEnumerator` is a very simple class that builds around the `KeyValueEnumerator()` you have returning `DictionaryEntry` objects and/or the `Key` and the `Value` (I'll say it's an implementation of the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern))

Comment: "If you are implementing a default interface `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`" He's not.